# Oracle multiple values in a single row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this query which inserts 4 new rows in my table. I don't want this. I want to insert a single row and separate values with `,`. How can I do this?

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTATION (NAME, VALUE, QUERY, INSERTDATE) 
     SELECT 'Datafile paths', name, 'select name from V$DATAFILE', SYSDATE 
     from V$DATAFILE;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot. @SMA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, aggregating several rows into a single comma-separated value is done with `LISTAGG`:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTATION (NAME, VALUE, QUERY, INSERTDATE) 
SELECT 'Datafile paths',
       LISTAGG(name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name), 
       'select name from V$DATAFILE', 
       SYSDATE 
FROM V$DATAFILE;
```

Beware of the 4000 character limit, as always...

Answer (score 1):

Try to concatenate all the values using "||" like:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTATION (NAME, VALUE, QUERY, INSERTDATE) 
 SELECT 'Datafile paths' || name || 'select name from V$DATAFILE' || SYSDATE, 'Datafile paths' || name || 'select name from V$DATAFILE' || SYSDATE, 'Datafile paths' || name || 'select name from V$DATAFILE' || SYSDATE, 'Datafile paths' || name || 'select name from V$DATAFILE' || SYSDATE
 from V$DATAFILE;
```

If you need to select just one row, then you would need to specify the where clause like:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTATION (NAME, VALUE, QUERY, INSERTDATE) 
 SELECT 'Datafile paths', name, 'select name from V$DATAFILE', SYSDATE 
 FROM V$DATAFILE
 WHERE myfield = 'foobar';
```